# Endless loop in v5.0.25 when changing permissions

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I've problem with the v5 SDK on iframe Facebook app...

When I download the v5 sdk and check it on Facebook everything is OK, BUT when I'm changing the permissions to : 'friends_birthday,email', I'm getting endless loop after I accept the app permissions.

I've checked the o'auth 2 and it's set on enabled.

This is the code I'm using:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Permissions = new[] { "friends_birthday,email" } };

    if (auth.Authorize())
    {
        ShowFacebookContent();
    }
}
```

Can some one help me here ?

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT !!!

The code for multiple permissions in the V5 should be:

```
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Permissions = new[] { "friends_birthday", "email" } };
```